# The equivalence class of the identity element of $G$ defined by $a \sim b$ iff $ab^{-1} \in H$ for $H\le G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, equivalence-relations

I already proved that $a \sim b$ is an equivalence relationship.

I think that identity element $e$ of $G$ is defined as: $b b^{-1}$ because $(ab^{-1})(bb^{-1}) = ab^{-1}$

Now I'm just realizing that I also have to prove that $e\ a = a$.

so $(aa^{-1})(ab^{-1}) = ab^{-1}$ as well.

so either $a a^{-1}$ or $b b^{-1}$ are both identity elements?

I'm also getting caught up on what an equivalence class for an identity element actually is.

Comment: $aa^{-1}=bb^{-1}=e$

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $a \sim e \Leftrightarrow ae^{-1}=a \in H$, the equivalence class of $e$ is $H$. More generally, the equivalence class of $b\in G$ is the right coset $Hb$.

Comment: I'm still new to the terminology of a coset but essentially the equivalence class of $e$ is the subgroup $H$ itself. Depending on what element $\in G$ is being referred to, the equivalence class is more specifically a partition of the subgroup $H$?

Comment: The equivalence relation is among the elements of $G$, so it induces a partition of $G$, which is then "sliced" into classes. One of these classes is $H$, to whom $e$ belongs along with all the other $ a \sim e$. Given $b\in G$, all the $a \sim b$ are such that $ab^{-1}=h$, for some $h \in H$, whence $[b]_\sim =\{a \in G\mid a\sim b\}= Hb$.

Answer (score 0):

A bit to unpack here.

First, the identity element $e$ of $G$ is not defined by $bb^{-1}$. It is *defined* as the (unique) element $e$ such that $ae=ea = a$ for all $a \in G$. This is the *definition*, so  don't have to prove that $ea = a$. As it happens, $aa^{-1}$ and $bb^{-1}$ are both the identity element (by definition of inverse elements).

So, what is the equivalence class of an element $a \in G$? By definition, it is the set of all $b \in G$ such that $a \sim b$. So, the equivalence class of $e \in G$ (the identity element) is the set of all $b$ such that $e \sim b$. Unwrapping the definition of $\sim$ tells us that the equivalence class we're looking for is the set of all $b$ such that $eb^{-1} = b^{-1} \in H$. But, $b^{-1} \in H$ if and only if $b \in H$, so the equivalence class of $e$ is just $H$.

Comment: Well, it is *a* definition, not *the* definition; there is more than one way to define groups and their identities.

Answer (score 0):

One way to view $a\sim_H b$ is to see it as equivalent to saying $a$ and $b$ differ by an element in $H$ with respect to the operation of the group. This is most clear when the operation is addition, since then $a\sim_H b$ iff $a-b\in H$.

As such, then, the equivalence class of $e$ is all $g\in G$ such that $g$ and $e$ differ by an element of $H$ (and I can write $g$ first as $\sim_H$ is symmetric as an equivalence relation); namely, $g\sim_H e$ iff $g=ge^{-1}\in H$.

Hence the equivalence class is

$$\begin{align}
[e]_{\sim_H}&:=\{ g\in G\mid e\sim_H g\}\\
&=H.
\end{align}$$